# button function doesn't work without any error - django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, upload

So i want to make models form to upload file mp3. I was copy the code from website, but suddenly it's not work. there's no error message in terminal or console too.

when i clicked button audiotrack, what my terminal shown just

```
[12/May/2022 22:11:00] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 8928
```

[console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9UNO5.png)

[my website frontend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6e6BG.png)

please help me to fix it. i will give my code :

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.views.decorators.csrf import ensure_csrf_cookie
from .forms import AudioForm
from .models import Audio_store
from MusicLockApp.forms import AudioForm

@ensure_csrf_cookie
def homepage(request):
    # return HttpResponse('homepage')
    return render(request, 'homepage.html')

def decode(request):
    # return HttpResponse('about')
    return render(request, 'decode.html')

def upload(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = AudioForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        return redirect("main:upload")
    form = AudioForm()
    audio = Audio_store.objects.all()
    return render(request=request, template_name="homepage.html", context={'form':form, 'audio':audio})
```

urls.py :

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
from django.urls import path, re_path
from django.conf import settings


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^decode/$', views.decode),
    url(r'^$', views.homepage),
    path('audio', views.Audio_store),
]

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class Audio_store(models.Model):
    record=models.FileField(upload_to='media/mp3')
```

forms.py:

```
from django import forms 
from .models import Audio_store

class AudioForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Audio_store
        fields=['record']
```

add settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'MusicLockApp',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'crispy_forms',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'assets'),
)

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

```html
{% block content %}  

            {% load crispy_forms_tags %} 

            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="row" style="margin-top: 20px; margin-right: 10px;">
                            <button type="button" class="dsnupload">
                                <i class="large material-icons" style="font-size: 50pt; margin-top: 10px;">file_upload</i>
                                <p style="font-weight: bold; color: white;">Insert file password</p>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <br>
                        <div class="row" style="margin-right: 10px;">
                            <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                            {% csrf_token %}
                            {{form|crispy}}
                            <button type="submit" class="dsnupload">
                                <i class="large material-icons" style="font-size: 50pt; margin-top: 10px;">audiotrack</i>
                                <p style="font-weight: bold; color: white;">Insert file audio (mp3)</p>
                            </button>
                            <p id="message"></p>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                        <br>
                        <div class="row" style="margin-right: 10px;">
                            <div class="col-1">
                                <label class="labels" style="color: white;">Key:</label>
                                <button type="submit" class="dsnupload"></button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-11">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="insert your key here">
                            </div>
                            <br> <br>
                            <a class="dsnhide" type="button" href="#" role="button">Hide it!</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
    
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="row" style="margin-top: 20px;">
                            <div class="card" style="height: 13rem;">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                  <h5 class="card-title" style="text-align: center;">
                                      Progressing now
                                  </h5>
                                  <br>
                                  <div class="progress">
                                    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="75" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 75%">75%</div>
                                  </div>
                                  <br> <br>
                                  <div class="text-center">
                                    <button id="obfuscate-button" onclick="obfuscate()">Play song</button>
                                    <a class="dsnbtn" type="button" href="#" role="button">Download</a>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <br>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="card">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                  <h5 class="card-title">Information Music</h5>
                                  <p class="card-text">Song :</p>
                                  <p class="card-text">Artist :</p>
                                  <p class="card-text">Album :</p>
                                  <p class="card-text">Year :</p>
                                  <p class="card-text">Genre :</p>
                                  <p class="card-text">Duration :</p>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            {% endblock %}
```

what i want is = when i click button insert audio file, we can choose file from local and when clicked button hide it, it will upload it to local folder.

[image: error]
[image: error1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you have two different views rendered into your  same `homepage` template. The `POST` method will never be sent to your DB. You have two options:

### 1. If you want different views, add it to `urlpatterns`, in your form put `action="{% url 'upload_url' %}"`

`views.py`

```
@ensure_csrf_cookie
def homepage(request):
    form = AudioForm()
    audio = Audio_store.objects.all()
    context = {'form': form, 'audio': audio}

    return render(request, 'homepage.html', context=context)

def decode(request):
    # return HttpResponse('about')
    return render(request, 'decode.html')

def upload(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = AudioForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))  # redirect previous page
    return redirect("main:homepage")
```

`urls.py`

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^decode/$', views.decode),
    url(r'^$', views.homepage),
    url(r'^upload/$', views.upload), # here
    path('audio', views.Audio_store),
]
```

`html`

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'main:upload' %}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

### 2. The simplest way is to render the form in the same page as the `POST` request.

`views.py`

```
def homepage(request):
    form = AudioForm()
    audio = Audio_store.objects.all()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = AudioForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        return redirect("main:homepage")

    context={'form':form, 'audio':audio}
    return render(request, "homepage.html", context=context)

def decode(request):
    # return HttpResponse('about')
    return render(request, 'decode.html')
```

This way, you don't need to add another `urlpattern` and modify your form `action`.

Comment: i tried your number 2. now i can choose file, but when i click button submit, there's error no such table: MusicLockApp_audio_store. i was add the screenshot

Comment: Assuming the `POST` request worked, the error message is clear. You either have not created or migrated your model to your DB.

Comment: but i don't want to use dataabase. just upload it to local folder, can i?

Comment: Yes, you can. But I'm afraid you have to reconstruct the form using custom form, not `ModelForm`. Because if you use `ModelForm`, Django will save the `path` of your file to your DB and your file to your local storage. Please refer to [this link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/file-uploads/) if you want only to save the file to your local storage.

Comment: so i tried use code with : from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect,
from django.shortcuts import render,
from .forms import UploadFileForm,
from .models import ModelWithFileField, ??

Comment: could you help me to make custom form? you can answer it to my new question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72224177/how-to-make-custom-form-without-database-django